# Laravel and Paypal

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I wish to play around with a sandbox account on Paypals classic API using this http://jslim.net/blog/2014/09/19/integrate-paypal-sdk-into-laravel-4/

I am at the part where I need to setup the config and it requires me to input a client_id and secret. For this I have created a sandbox account, but the only details I can get from this account is the email, password, and certificate.

How would I go about getting a client_id and secret?

Answer (score 1):

You need to login in the **[developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com)** area with your normal login data. On the left menu click over **My Apps** and create a new one.

Here the direct **[link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/createapp)** to do this (after login).